# Why is this Brownian motion event not measurable w.r.t. the natural filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, filtrations

In my lecture on stochastic processes it is stated that the natural filtration $\mathcal{F_t}^0=\sigma(\forall s\leq t: \omega\mapsto \omega(s)$ is measurable$)$ is not a good choice for Brownian motion because for example
$$
L=\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log|\log t|}}
$$
is not measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}^0$ but w.r.t. $\mathcal{F_t}=\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal{F_s}^0$.

Why is this the case? I have no clue why $L$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and why not $\mathcal{F}^0$-measurable and it's nowhere explained.

Can someone of you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: The natural filtration is such that $\mathcal{F_0^0}=\{\phi, \Omega\}$ because it's trivial sigma algebra (a $B_0=0$), so if $L$ is not constant you are done. Using time inversion you can look at the law of iterated logarithm to get a non constant result for L unless mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for each $\epsilon>0$,
$$
L=\inf_{0< s<\epsilon, s\in\Bbb Q}\sup_{t\in(0,s), t\in\Bbb Q}{B_t\over \sqrt{2t\log|\log t|}}
$$
is $\mathcal F^0_\epsilon$ measurable. 
(I have replaced the limit in your definition of $L$ with limit superior; the latter always exists, the former doesn't exist, for a.e. Brownian path.) It follows that $L$ is $\mathcal F_0$ measurable.  On the other hand, $\mathcal F^0_0=\sigma\{B_0\}$ and $L$ is clearly not a function of $B_0$ alone.